# SuperBGImage script tutorial

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a tutorial of the jQuery PlugIn SuperBGImage (http://demo.andreaseberhard.de/superbgimage/demo.html). Unfortunately the site is no more online, i try google but nothing really found. Is there a chance, that maybe somebody out there has a description/examples of using this class?

Thanks for help
regards
thomas

Comment: http://www.esta-rohr.de/html/js/SuperBGImage/demo_inline.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can See Via CAche Of Google
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:u1rNeGhcoCUJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/32840827/superbgimage-script-tutorial+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk